# Appending column from one dataframe to another dataframe with multiple matches in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

My question is an extension of this question:

[Check if value in a dataframe is between two values in another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59408188/check-if-value-in-a-dataframe-is-between-two-values-in-another-dataframe)

df1

```
    df1_Col     df1_start
0   A1          1200        
1   B2          4000        
2   B2          2500
```

df2

```
    df2_Col     df2_start   df2_end       data
0   A1          1000        2000          DATA_A1
1   A1          900         1500          DATA_A1_A1
**2   A1          2000        3000          DATA_A1_A1_A1**
2   B1          2000        3000          DATA_B1
3   B2          2000        3000          DATA_B2
```

output:

```
    df1_Col     df1_start     data
0   A1          1200          DATA_A1;DATA_A1_A1
1   B2          4000          
2   B2          2500          DATA_B2
```

I am comparing the value of `df1_Col` to match with `df2_Col` and `df1_start` to be within the range of `df2_start` and `df2_end`, then add values of `data` column in `df1`. If there multiple matches, then `data` can combine with any delimiter like ';'.

The code is as follows:

```
for v,ch in zip(df1.df1_start, df1.df1_Col):
        df3 = df2[(df2['df2_start'] < v) & (df2['df2_end'] > v) & (df2['df2_Col'] ==ch)]
        data = df3['data']
        df1['data'] = data
```

Loops are used because file is huge.

EDIT:
[image]

Looking forward for your assistance.

Comment: why are you getting 4000 in expected output bcz it doesn't lies between df2_start and df2_end?

Comment: Because it is the part of df1 and appending the column `data` to df1. It can be blank or dash to see that this row didn't have any matches.

Comment: I think this should be `1200` instead of `1000` in `df1_start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

try via `merge()`+`groupby()`+`agg()`:

Left merge on df1 then check if 'df1_start' falls between 'df2_start' and 'df2_end' and creating column 'data' and setting it's value equal to None.Then we are grouping on `['df1_Col','df1_start']` and joining the values of 'date' seperated by `';'` by dropping None:

```
out=df1.merge(df2,left_on='df1_Col',right_on='df2_Col',how='left',sort=True)
out.loc[~out['df1_start'].between(out['df2_start'], out['df2_end']), 'data'] = None
out=out.groupby(['df1_Col','df1_start'],as_index=False,sort=False)['data'].agg(lambda x:';'.join(x.dropna()))
```

output of `out`:

```
   df1_Col  df1_start       data
0   A1          1200        DATA_A1;DATA_A1_A1
1   B2          4000    
2   B2          2500        DATA_B2
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for it. But the only issue I am facing with the first script currently is that it adds the asterisk row (edited in the question) also in the data although it does not match the criteria of being in between the`df2_start` and `df2_end`. The second script adds ";" for the rows it is matched as "False". For example, the data table looks like this "DATA_A1;;;;;;;;DATA_A1_A1" considering I have more than 60,000 rows, the data column is kinda ambiguous.

Comment: I have tried the modified code:`out=out.groupby(['chr','start','end'],as_index=False,sort=False)['data'].agg(lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna()))` but didn't owrk.

Comment: @aso so both script is working fine for you except that data column looks like this `"DATA_A1;;;;;;;;DATA_A1_A1"`?

Comment: First script gives a false positive `data` value mentioned with asterisk in the question `DATA_A1;DATA_A1_A1;DATA_A1_A1_A1` although the third entry doesn't match the criteria in between the range `df2_start` and `df2_end` (Added a picture in the question for your understanding). Second script gives me the ambiguous `data` column.

Comment: @aso thanks sir for the efforts and patience.....updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Perfectly worked... Really appreciate your help.