# Check if value in pandas dataframe is within any two values of two other columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have two dataframes of different length.
dfSamples (63012375 rows) and
dfFixations (200000 rows).

```
dfSamples = pd.DataFrame({'tSample':[4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]})  
dfFixations = pd.DataFrame({'tStart':[4,12],'tEnd':[8,14]})
```

I would like to check each value in dfSamples if it is within any two ranges given in dfFixations and then assign a label to this value. I have found this: [Check if value in a dataframe is between two values in another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59408188/check-if-value-in-a-dataframe-is-between-two-values-in-another-dataframe), but the loop solution is terribly slow and I cannot make any other solution work.

Working (but very slow) example:

```
labels = np.empty_like(dfSamples['tSample']).astype(np.chararray)
for i, fixation in dfFix.iterrows():
    log_range = dfSamples['tSample'].between(fixation['tStart'], fixation['tEnd'])
    labels[log_range] = 'fixation'
labels[labels != 'fixation'] = 'no_fixation'
dfSamples['labels'] = labels
```

Following this example: [Performance of Pandas apply vs np.vectorize to create new column from existing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c) I have tried to vectorize this but with no success.

```
def check_range(samples, tstart, tend):
    log_range = (samples > tstart) & (samples < tend)
    return log_range
fixations = list(map(check_range, dfSamples['tSample'], dfFix['tStart'], dfFix['tEnd']))
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`IntervalIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html) with [`IntervalIndex.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.get_indexer.html) , if not match is returned `-1`, so checked and set ouput in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
i = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(dfFixations['tStart'],
                                 dfFixations['tEnd'], 
                                 closed="both")
pos = i.get_indexer(dfSamples['tSample'])
dfSamples['labels'] = np.where(pos != -1, "fixation", "no_fixation")

print (dfSamples)
   tSample       labels
0        4     fixation
1        6     fixation
2        8     fixation
3       10  no_fixation
4       12     fixation
5       14     fixation
```

**Performance**: In ideal nice sorted not overlap data, in real should be performance different, the best test it.

```
dfSamples = pd.DataFrame({'tSample':range(10000)})  
dfFixations = pd.DataFrame({'tStart':range(0, 10000, 5),'tEnd':range(2, 10000, 5)})
    


In [165]: %%timeit
     ...: labels = np.empty_like(dfSamples['tSample']).astype(np.chararray)
     ...: for i, fixation in dfFixations.iterrows():
     ...:     log_range = dfSamples['tSample'].between(fixation['tStart'], fixation['tEnd'])
     ...:     labels[log_range] = 'fixation'
     ...: labels[labels != 'fixation'] = 'no_fixation'
     ...: dfSamples['labels'] = labels
     ...: 
     ...: 
1.25 s ± 52.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


In [168]: %%timeit
     ...: ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(dfFixations['tStart'], dfFixations['tEnd'], closed="both")
     ...: dfSamples["labels1"] =  np.where(dfSamples["tSample"].apply(ii.contains).apply(any), "fixation", "no_fixation")
     ...: 
315 ms ± 18.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


In [170]: %%timeit
     ...: ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(dfFixations['tStart'], dfFixations['tEnd'], closed="both")
     ...: contained = np.logical_or.reduce(piso.contains(ii, dfSamples["tSample"], include_index=False), axis=0)
     ...: dfSamples["labels1"] = np.where(contained, "fixation", "no_fixation")
     ...: 
82.4 ms ± 213 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

```
In [166]: %%timeit
     ...: s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(dfFixations['tStart'], dfFixations['tEnd'], closed="both")
     ...: pos = s.get_indexer(dfSamples['tSample'])
     ...: dfSamples['labels'] = np.where(pos != -1, "fixation", "no_fixation")
     ...: 
27.8 ms ± 1.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Great answer! For my data set, this is 10x faster than my solution. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I am getting the error message "InvalidIndexError: cannot handle overlapping indices; use IntervalIndex.get_indexer_non_unique" even though my intervals are not overlapping. If I use `[ii.overlaps(x) for x in ii]` only the diagonal is True

Comment: @heldm - hmmm, maybe there is at least one overlapped value. Another solution also not working?

Comment: Right again. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**setup**

```
dfSamples = pd.DataFrame({'tSample':[4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]})  
dfFixations = pd.DataFrame({'tStart':[4,12],'tEnd':[8,14]})
```

**solution**

Create an interval index from your start and end points

```
ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(dfFixations['tStart'], dfFixations['tEnd'], closed="both")
```

`ii.contains` is a method which checks if a point is contained by each interval in the interval index, eg

```
dfSamples["tSample"].apply(ii.contains)
```

gives

```
0     [True, False]
1     [True, False]
2     [True, False]
3    [False, False]
4     [False, True]
5     [False, True]
Name: tSample, dtype: object
```

We're going to take this result, apply `any` function to each element (a list) to get a `pandas.Series` of booleans, which we can then use with `numpy.where`

```
dfSamples["labels"] =  np.where(dfSamples["tSample"].apply(ii.contains).apply(any), "fixation", "no_fixation")
```

the result

```
   tSample       labels
0        4     fixation
1        6     fixation
2        8  no_fixation
3       10  no_fixation
4       12     fixation
5       14  no_fixation
```

**edit: faster version**

Using [`piso`](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) v0.6.0

```
import piso
import numpy as np

ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(dfFixations['tStart'], dfFixations['tEnd'], closed="both")
contained = np.logical_or.reduce(piso.contains(ii, dfSamples["tSample"], include_index=False), axis=0)
dfSamples["labels"] = np.where(contained, "fixation", "no_fixation")
```

This will run in a similar time to @jezrael's solution, however it can handle cases where intervals overlaps  eg

```
dfFixations = pd.DataFrame({'tStart':[4,5,12],'tEnd':[8,9,14]})
```

**note**: I am the creator of piso. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, this seems to be even slower than interrows for me. Took about 5x longer than my solution above

Comment: I may have a faster solution for you but I need to know how your intervals are "closed". In your first solution your intervals are closed on both ends, and in your second they're closed on neither.

Comment: Would be great! Whatever is fastest will be best in this case. Preferably, only 10 would get the label 'no_fixation'.