# Python (pandas) - check if value in one df is between ANY pair in another (unequal) df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As a minimal example consider the following two df (notice their sizes are not equal):

```
df
   min_val  max_val
0        0        4
1        5        9
2       10       14
3       15       19 
4       20       24
5       25       29

df1
   val
0    1
1    6
2    2
3   Nan
4    34
```

I am trying to check whether each value in df1 can be found **within any** pair in df. The output should be a new dataframe that will contain the val column of df1 plus the pair within which it was found plus an extra column with a name tag let's say 'within' and 'not within'. So the output should look like:

```
   val   min_val  max_val  nameTag
0   1      0        4       within
1   6      5        9       within
2   2      0        4       within
3   Nan    Nan      Nan     not within
4   34     Nan      Nan     not within
```

So far, any solutions I have found do the searches line-by-line missing the val 2 in df1 which is within the pair 0-4 in df (some posts that did not work for me [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59408188/check-if-value-in-a-dataframe-is-between-two-values-in-another-dataframe), and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617845/how-to-select-rows-in-a-dataframe-between-two-values-in-python-pandas)).

Any pointers/advice/solutions will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
tmp = pd.merge_asof(df1.reset_index().sort_values(by='val').dropna(),
                    df.sort_values(by='min_val').astype(float),
                    left_on='val', right_on='min_val'
                   ).set_index('index').reindex(df1.index)

df1['nameTag'] = np.where(tmp['val'].le(tmp['max_val']), 'within', 'not within')
```

Or an [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html):

```
s = pd.Series('within', pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df['min_val'], df['max_val']))

df1['nameTag'] =s.reindex(df1['val']).fillna('no within').to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
    val     nameTag
0   1.0      within
1   6.0      within
2   2.0      within
3   NaN  not within
4  34.0  not within
```

Comment: Wow, such a fast response @mozway brilliant :-).  ```merge_asof``` is not a pandas function I am familiar with. Is there a way to grab the pair from df where the value "belong to"? I will try to work it out myself but if you could save me time it would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, if you look at `tmp` this is exactly doing that. You could then simply merge it with `df1`: `df1.merge(tmp, on='val')`

Comment: So many thanks @mozway, appreciated